# How to instal scipy package on windows?

Tags: python, scipy, package

I downloaded the scipy package as wheel, the last version for windows 64 bits scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win32

when i use

```
pip install scipy-0.18.1-cp36-cp36m-win64.whl
```

this command display

```
   numpy-1.12.0b1+mkl-cp36-cp36m-win64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

what is the problem?

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: `conda` would rescue you: https://www.continuum.io/downloads

Comment: @Code-Apprentice windows 10

Comment: @alvas: thank you this helped me, now it work

Answer (score 1):

1) To get precompiled packages for Windows, have a look at Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries or use a distribution like Winpython (just works) or Anaconda (more complex) which provide an entire preconfigured environment with lots of packages from the scientific python stack.

2) Installing with pip

You can install the numpy and scipy wheels on Windows with pip in one step if you use the appropriate link from Gohlke's Unofficial Windows Binaries (mentioned by sebix) and run the Windows command prompt as Administrator. For example, in Python 3.5, you would simply use something like this:

```
# numpy-1.9.3+mkl for Python 3.5 on Win AMD64
pip3.5 install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/xmshzit7/numpy-1.9.3+mkl-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl

# scipy-0.16.1 for Python 3.5 on Win AMD64
pip3.5 install http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/xmshzit7/scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl
```

or you can look here -> https://www.scipy.org/install.html

Comment: i don't know why i always i have this message in red color: scipy-0.16.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: your computer system is 32bit or 64bit ?

Comment: 64bit with RAM 8GB

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, try using Python(x,y) - a scientific distribution of Python which comes with scipy bundled.